# Simulate a key press in c on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, inputstream, simulation

I want to simulate key press say 'Ctrl+P' without touching the keyboard on my Ubuntu PC from a C program.
Basically I just want to include my multiple key press commands in the keyboard input stream.
How can I do it.

Moreover is it possible to simulate the multimedia keys such as play/pause, stop, etc. found on the keyboard.
If yes then how?